# Once I have a database project in Visual Studio, if I edit a stored procedure or view, how do I apply the changes to the server?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008

Once I have a database project in Visual Studio, if I edit a stored procedure or view, how do I apply the changes to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution Explorer ... Right Click Project ... Open properties .. Build tab ... Set target db to your server.

Then back to Solution Explorer ... Right click ... Rebuild ... then when done Right click and Deploy.